# Google Play: Unable to verify core functionality of app: Video Error

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, google-play

I'm trying to submit my app to play for the first time

Does my app use permissions like: Read Call Log... for the purpose of identifying numbers outside the address book and blocking specific numbers

I have checked check in `Default Phone handler`, `Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking` in `Permissions declaration form`.

But google team refused with the reason:

> **Unable to verify core functionality of app: Video Error**
>
> You submitted a permission declaration that specifies the following core
> functionality: Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality
> usage while default handler). However, the video you submitted does
> not demonstrate the functionality necessary to verify and approve your
> use case declaration (for example, if your app uses SMS for account
> verification, your video should clearly show this). Please re-submit a
> Permissions Declaration Form with a corresponding video that
> demonstrates the core app functionality in your use case declaration.

My video instructions link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UgVrQcasCKCfsSVax1icpEir-lG9E6oq/view?usp=sharing

Can you tell me how my video should meet google's needs, I have spent a lot of time on this problem

Many thanks !